# Trying to get data from database and show into dropbox

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get data from a specific column "Device Name" and display it into the dropbox I have created. This seems to not working at all. Could you please help me. I am new to php and still learning. I would appreciate your help. Thanks!

```
<php?
$hostName = "localhost";
$dbusername="root";
$dbpassword='';
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostName, $dbusername, '' ) or die("Could not   connect");
$selected = mysql_select_db("test", $dbhandle);
$query = "SELECT * FROM `devicehotsheet`";
$result1 = mysql_query($selected, $query);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body onload="hideTotal()">
<form method="POST" id="device" class="device">
<center class="all">
  <div class="data">
    <label class="req">Select The Device</label>
    <select class="selectDevice" id="selectDevice" onChange="calculateTotal()">
      <?php while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)):;?>
      <option><?php echo $row1[1];?></option>
      <?php endwhile;?>
    </select>
```

Comment: `<php?` - try `<?php`

Comment: Can you be more precise about **what exactly** is not working? Is it just the typo at the beginning of your script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me. Try this one:

```
<?php
$hostName = "localhost";
$dbusername="root";
$dbpassword='';
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostName, $dbusername, '' ) or die("Could not   connect");
$selected = mysql_select_db("test", $dbhandle);
$query = "SELECT * FROM `devicehotsheet`";
//Changed line of code below:
$result1 = mysql_query($query, $dbhandle);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body onload="hideTotal()">
<form method="POST" id="device" class="device">
<center class="all">
  <div class="data">
    <label class="req">Select The Device</label>
    <select class="selectDevice" id="selectDevice" onChange="calculateTotal()">
      <?php while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)):;?>
      <option><?php echo $row1[1];?></option>
      <?php endwhile;?>
    </select>
  </div>
</center>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was close!! Thank you for the help and I get it why did this makes sense. Anyways, I have more question. I have a database where there are numbers infront of different names. I want to create another selection box with one option. However, the number behind that option changes depending on the name I have chosen in the first dropbox. How can i achieve that ?